# What's the best way to copy files from an ext3 file system to a NTFS and maintain the ownership and permissions?

Tags: linux, permissions, cp, ntfs, ext3

I need to transfer over 1 Tb of data from a share on an ext3 file system that our corporate office uses. The share contains files with different owners and groups and needs to be copied over maintaining these permissions.

Comment: Do you need to copy from ext3 to NTFS, or are you using the NTFS filesystem as a transitory storage between two unix-native filesystems? Are you copying from or to ext3, by the way (your title and your body disagree)? How is the share accessible (Samba, presumably, but set up how)?

Comment: We have been running this share from samba on a Gentoo box.  Most who use the share are logged into the domain here with Windows 2k3 boxes for the DC's.  We decided to do away with samba shares and move to a windows share since file permission management will be more straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

After experimenting with this, I have found that the best way to achieve this is to mount the SAMBA shares in Windows Server, and use Robocopy to sync the files.  It will do a mirror copy if you want it to.  It's a very robust file copy tool in windows (later versions) I knew nothing about prior to today.

In fact, it has a /SECFIX option that will fix security information on files already copied.  I am testing this functionality against a rsync copy made of the ext3 fs we are moving.  With any luck, before days end I will have a complete up to date copy of the corporate share including correct ownership and permissions!