# Chmod is not working on ntfs-3g partition

Tags: linux, chown

my `chmod` doesn't work properly.

I just reinstalled my manjaro distro (formated only the root, non the /home).

This folder resides on a ntfs partition (I already have ntfs-3g installed), I only need to set my user as proprietary of this folder:

```bsh
~/backup ❯ ls -al
totale 4
drwxr-xr-x 1 root users    0 13 ago 10.08 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root users 4096 13 ago 11.32 ..
```

Then I change permissions inside

```bsh
~/backup ❯ sudo chown -R $USER .
```

But this is the result again:

```bsh
~/backup ❯ ls -al
totale 4
drwxr-xr-x 1 root users    0 13 ago 10.08 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root users 4096 13 ago 11.32 ..
~/backup ❯
```

Do you guys have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows and Linux have a very different user and permissions model that is incompatible.  For either `chmod` or `chown` to work, the file system needs to support users and permissions in a Linux-like way.  NTFS is a Windows file system and so these commands can't possibly work.

One thing you can do is to mount the NTFS partition specifying a different user and mode for all of the files / directories:

```
mount -o uid=userid,gid=groupid,dmask=022,fmask=133 /path/to/disk /mnt
```

This will mount with specified user and group giving directories mode `755` and files mode `644`.

Comment: Thanks, I solved mounting the disk on fstab with this options: `UUID=XXXXXXX   /mnt/shared ntfs-3g defaults,noatime,uid=1000,gid=users,dmask=022,fmask=133  0   0
`